# Error 800A03F2 VB Script to detect idle time using the GetLastInputInfo

Tags: vbscript

I am having an error on line 1 character 9 for the below vb script. I am using the GetLastInputInfo to detect the idle time..
I know this kind of error is from using reserved words as variable in vb, but I do not think I am using a reserved word.

I am not using any forms and will call this script using a task schedule.

Any ideas on this? Thanks!

```
Private Type InforTest
   cbSize As Long
   dwTime As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetLastInputInfo Lib "user32" (plii As Any) As Long

Sub Idle()

   Dim lii As InforTest
   Dim idletime as single

   lii.cbSize = Len(lii)
   Call GetLastInputInfo(lii)

   idletime  =  (GetTickCount() - lii.dwTime) / 1000)/3600 'Get idle time in hours

   if idletime  > 0.15
        WScript.Echo now
        'Do something

   End if


End Sub
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like VBA or VB6. VBScript doesn't allow access to the Win32 API (or typed variables).

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try a different approach..